# Azure AD B2C Custom Policies: Change styling of social IDP buttons on sign in page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is there anyway to change the styling of the social IDP buttons when using custom policies in Azure AD B2C? For reference here's what they look like when implemented via custom policy:

[image]

And here is an example when using the user flows:

[image]

Ideally I'd like my screenshot from the first image to look a bit more like the example in the second image. I understand how to change the text on the button but I'm more referring to the color and the icon. Have scoured the documentation but bit of a custom policy noob and can't find anything that covers this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little tinkering I figured out the solution:

The styling of these IDP buttons is related to their 'TargetClaimsExchangeId' in the custom policy orchestration step. While this id can be set to anything you like, setting it to the relevant Id eg: "MicrosoftAccountExchange" or "GoogleExchange" will invoke the correct styling. This isn't really made clear anywhere on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to customize styles of each element while using azure AD B2C custom policies.
It's explained nicely here on how to use custom html files and override styles in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). Please read through the whole thing.

[Refer to this GitHub repository](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/html-templates) with HTML files that you can deploy to your storage account or similar and you can start working.

If you are familiar with HTML and CSS, this should be a straightforward styling changes and using custom icons etc based on your requirement.

Comment: Not exactly relevant to my requirement here but useful information nonetheless for anyone looking to override the base styling of their page. See accepted answer for solution.